# How to escape comma in SOQL

Tags: soql

UPDATE:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Signature FROM User WHERE Signature = 'This is a test, 
this is a another test, 
this is a last test'
```

the above query returns the data only after I have split that in lines

Any explanation? I do not see any HTML code in the field

END UPDATE

I'm trying to write simple SOQL query that has comma in it.

> SELECT Id, Name, Signature FROM User WHERE Signature = 'This is a
>   test, this is a another test, this is a last test'

If i run the above SOQL I do not get any result and I even tried with `LIKE`

> SELECT Id, Name, Signature FROM User WHERE Signature LIKE 'This is a
>   test, this is a another test, this is a last test%'

Is there a way escape the `comma`?

Comment: Did you try simply replacing the comma with a %?

Comment: You could also use `_` as a wildcard that matches a *single* character.

Comment: Are you trying to query records where the Signature is literally `This is a test, this is a another test, this is a last test`, or are your commas separating 3 separate possible signatures that you're trying to search for (e.g. `Signature = 'This is a test' OR Signature = 'this is another test' OR Signature = 'this a last test'`)?

Comment: So, there are literal blank lines in your signature? You'd use `\n` to escape those. The commas are just fine.

Comment: did not work if I use the `\n` to escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I able to make it work, hope this will help others:

```
string s = 'This is a test,'+'\r\n'+'this is a another test,'+'\r\n'+
'this is a last test';

SELECT Id, Name, Signature FROM User WHERE Signature =: s;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only characters you need to escape are listed in [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm), which are `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, `\b`, `\f`, `\'`, `\"`, `\\`, `\_`, and `\%`. Commas do not need to be escaped. The most typical cause for a query not to return values is duplicated spaces (e.g. `This is  a test` instead of `This is a test`). Try querying the record and checking out what's actually in the field. Also, there might be HTML in the field, which you would also need to account for.

Comment: I have updated my question, any explanation to it?

Comment: @NickKahn Perhaps you're on Windows? In which case, the field might literally contain `\r\n`. What if you said `SELECT Name, Signature FROM User WHERE Signature LIKE 'This is a test,%'`? I would expect that to work. The point is, you'd have to work what's in the whitespace if you wanted to include it in the filter.